# Why does this TypeScript type result in an array-like structure, though it looks like an object-like type?

Tags: typescript

```
type Item<T extends string = string> = {
  item: T
}

type Card<T extends string = string> = string | Item<T>;

type Group<T extends Card[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Item<infer Name> ? Name : never
}

const group: Group<["book", { item: "SomeBookTitle" }]> =
  [null as never, "SomeBookTitle"]
```

Based on how type `Group` is defined, I expect `group` to have an object shape, perhaps as

```
const group = { "SomeBookTitle": "SomeBookTitle" }
```

How does it end up as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Group` is defined as a mapped type. Although mapped type use the `{}` as objects do they have their own rules about what the output type will be. For a homomorphic mapped type, if the input type is a tuple or an array, this property of the original type will be preserver.  This behavior was introduces in 3.1 with [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063).

I am not sure why you are expecting `Group<["book", { item: "SomeBookTitle" }]>` to be taht particular object type (`{ "SomeBookTitle": "SomeBookTitle" }`) nothing in that mapped type suggests it should be, even before this PR, you woudl have ended up with `{ 0: never, 1: "SomeBookTitle" }` plus a bunch of array methods.

If you want to get that type the mapped type would have to look something like this:

```
type GroupKeys<T extends Card[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Item<infer Name> ? Name : never
}[number]

type Group<T extends Card[]> = {
  [K in GroupKeys<T>]: string // chose string not sure what you want here 
}


const group: Group<["book", { item: "SomeBookTitle" }]> = {
  SomeBookTitle: "",
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsA8AVKEAe8B2ATAzlPsAE4CW2A5lALxGkWUB8tUA3gLABQUUZ8CAFxQU3AL7duoSFADCAQxK5U6LBDyFi5Kqy2MWdPToA+sAaiYBuSV2nQA4iQD2AVzABpCCHwrMOAnKKuADaALoG7Ny8we582FAA1l5OAGYiocIoMaGq-oRwiEgUKRAkUABy8ggQLAD8FVXQwtgQAG6l4sHYLggARqWhNnZQjq5gvmoagUphEZw8UDFxI85unt4WGfTa1AD0u1AAxgAWTvjQRtTYTsBELiTQAO7H8rcgrlCP8ti3x6XQ4hs3EOTmwxCglFWYGEozcSGCACJek4nAkEQAadh8ATCBEAZSc1QAQiiEih+AAbCAIqBicKsea8AnE0nk4BU3EYwFcYGg8GQsYATgZUHxhIgJNRbKpCNxzIlrMp1NpQA)